# Adding IBOulets to custom UIView subclass crashes 'is not key-value compliant'

Tags: ios, objective-c, inheritance, uiview

I have created two different subviews `EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion` and `EPStudentProgressMultipleChoiceQuestion`. They both inherit from `EPStudentProgressQuestion` as they both subviews share some common information and behaviours.

Each one of the views has its own XIB file.

Inside `EPStudentProgressQuestion` there is the following code:

```
#import "EPStudentProgressQuestion.h"

@interface EPStudentProgressQuestion ()

@property (assign, nonatomic) EPStudentProgressQuestionType questiontype;

@end

@implementation EPStudentProgressQuestion

#pragma mark - UIView lifecycle

- (instancetype)initWityQuestionType:(EPStudentProgressQuestionType)questionType {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.questiontype = questionType;

        [self setupView];
    }

    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

    if (self) {
        [self setupView];
    }

    return self;
}

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder];

    if (self) {
        [self setupView];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Private methods

- (void)setupView {
    NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
    UIView *view = [[bundle loadNibNamed:[self nibNameForQuestionType] owner:[self class] options:nil] firstObject];
    view.frame = self.bounds;

    [self.layer setCornerRadius:2.f];
    [self.layer setBorderWidth:1.f];
    [self.layer setBorderColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:232/255.f alpha:1.f].CGColor];
    [self setClipsToBounds:YES];

    [self setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
    [self addSubview:view];
}

- (NSString*)nibNameForQuestionType {
    switch (self.questiontype) {
        case EPStudentProgressQuestionTypeOpen:
            return @"EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion";

        case EPStudentProgressQuestionTypeMultipleChoice:
            return @"EPStudentProgressMultipleChoiceQuestion";
    }
}
```

As you can see, very simple code.

As I said above, each `EPStudentProgressQuestion` view has its own XIB file, connecting the `Files Owner` through the `Identity Inspector` class.

This is `EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion`:

```
#import "EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion.h"

@interface EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblQuestion;

@end

@implementation EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion

@end
```

Exactly the same for `EPStudentProgressMultipleChoiceQuestion` just without any `IBOutlet`. But as soon as I create `IBOutlets` to any of those views, I get the error `... IBOutlet is not key-value compliant...`

Without the `IBOutlets` everything works fine. Each view loads correctly and it's well placed in the view I want to. But as soon as I link some `IBOutlets` from the XIB to the corresponding class, it crashes...

This is the crash:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<EPStudentProgressQuestion 0x1020196b0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key lblQuestion.'
```

And this is how I instantiate the `EPStudentProgressQuestion` view:

```
EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion *questionView = [[EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion alloc] initWityQuestionType: EPStudentProgressQuestionTypeOpen];
[self.vQuestionsContainer addSubview:questionView];
```

Any idea on how to be able to link `IBOutlets` without having problems?

Thank you in advance!!

**EDIT:**

If I change the `bundle` and `owner` classes as follows:

```
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion class]];
    NSArray *views = [bundle loadNibNamed:[self nibNameForQuestionType] owner:[EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion class] options:nil];
    UIView *view = [views firstObject];
```

I get the same error but instead of `EPStudentProgressQuestion` I get the error for `EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion`...

**EDIT 2:**
Test project link: https://mega.nz/#!oBhWkawC!RSOzrPOfq_UTVWd3jraRkneuCIyIkS61PKGeca2Bilc

Comment: Please edit your question to include (1) your `IBOutlet` declarations and (2) the complete error message you're receiving.

Comment: @robmayoff done, sorry!

Comment: Can you show the code where you instantiate the view controller from the xib?

Comment: @Paulw11 done! :)

Comment: Your error message says that you're loading an object of type `EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion`, which is neither `QuestionViewOne` nor `QuestionViewTwo`.

Comment: @robmayoff I shortened the names for better understanding. `EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion` = `QuestionViewOne`

Comment: Since you're changing details without telling us, it's impossible at this point for us to know if you've accidentally changed a detail that is in fact the cause of your problem.

Comment: Please show your *actual code* and the *actual error message*. You almost certainly have a wrong class name somewhere.

Comment: @robmayoff I am now showing the real code. Copied and pasted exactly what I have on Xcode. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @Paulw11 I am already showing the real code. Sorry for the misunderstanding...

Comment: It is like `EPStudentProgressQuestion` thinks that the `IBOutlet` is set to him, but it is not, it is set to `EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion`.

Comment: I have uploaded a sample project with only those 3 classes to MEGA. Download link at question. If you add the relation with the available `IBOutlet` it will crash. Right now it won't crash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem that's crashing you is that you are passing `[self class]` instead of just `self` as the nib owner. Change your nib loading line to this:

```
NSArray *views = [bundle loadNibNamed:[self nibNameForQuestionType] owner:self options:nil];
```

You have another problem which is that you're loading the nib twice. In `initWityQuestionType:`, you call `[super init]`. What you don't realize is `-[UIView init]` calls `[self initWithFrame:CGRectZero]`. So you end up calling into your overridden `initWithFrame:`, which calls `setupView`. Then when it returns back to `initWityQuestionType:`, that also calls `setupView`.

I recommend you get rid of your `initWithFrame:` override entirely.

Comment: Thank you!! Omg, I wrote that piece of code very quickly and I made that stupid mistake... And I did not know that thing about the `UIView` init. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Your view controller may have the wrong class in your xib. Please change the UIView class name not the in the File's Owner like the pic

[image]

Also you called a [self setup] method in:

```
- (instancetype)initWityQuestionType:(EPStudentProgressQuestionType)questionType {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.questiontype = questionType;
        [self setupView];
    }
    return self;
}
```

You don't need to call it again

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
}
```

and

```
- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
}
```

it is creating a init loop and causing a memory leak.

Comment: I think I have set the correct class. `EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion.xib` -> `File's Owner` -> `Identity Inspector` -> `Class` set to `EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion`. The same for `EPStudentProgressMultipleChoiceQuestion.xib`, but the `Class` is set to `EPStudentProgressMultipleChoiceQuestion`

Answer (score 0):

Your crash indicates that `EPStudentProgressQuestion` (your superclass) is not key-value compliant. This means at the point where you are accessing the IBOutlet you have a reference to `EPStudentProgressQuestion` instead of either `EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion` or `EPStudentProgressMultipleChoiceQuestion`.

Just check the code where you are using the new IBOutlets and either change the type of the variable used there or add a cast to the correct class.

Comment: I edited the question where you can see that it also crashes when instead of loading `bundle` and `owner` of `self` I load the one for `EPStudentProgressOpenQuestion`. Moreover, I do not use that `IBOutlet`, just the creation of it (link between XIB and .h or .m) makes the app crash.

Comment: I have uploaded a sample project with only those 3 classes to MEGA. Download link at question. If you add the relation with the available `IBOutlet` it will crash. Right now it won't crash.